# Symfony2 validate text input when containing something only

Tags: validation, symfony, annotations, assert

I want to validate a form which holds a dropdown menu and a text input field.

The user can choose a project from the dropdown menu. If he wants to create a new project he can use the text input field next to the dropdown menu.

Here is my upload type:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->setAction('upload')
        ->setMethod('POST')

        // project name dropdown menu
        ->add('projectname', 'choice' , array(
            'label' => 'upload_project_label',
            'choices'  => $this->projects,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control some',
                'required' => 'true'
            )
        ))

        // newprojectname text input
        ->add('newprojectname', 'text', array(
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'required' => false,
                    'placeholder' => 'upload_newprojectname_placeholder'
                )
            )
        )
...
```

And this is a snippet from my upload entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 *
 * @var string $projectname
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $projectname;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 *
 * @var string $newprojectname
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min = 3,
 *     max = 7,
 *     minMessage = "min message",
 *     maxMessage = "max message"
 * )
 */
protected $newprojectname;
```

My question is is there a possibility of a query to check if the field newproject is set (i.e. a string is entered)? And if so let the Assert annotation  do its job.

Comment: I don't understand... Do you want check if the field is not empty, and then what?

Comment: You can create a [`Callback`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) assert.

Comment: @pabgaran - I want to check if something is entered in the field and if so check the entered value with Assert annotations. Is that clear enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done a number of ways, all of which will likely satisfy your requirements.

1. Use a [custom callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) - this is the quickest and most straightforward
2. Use an [expression validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html) - a lot of people have issues with embedding a meta-language within PHP which is perfectly valid but this is another quick-ish way of doing things
3. Use [group sequences](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#group-sequence), specifically the [group sequence provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#group-sequence-providers) functionality

Which one you choose is up to you but callbacks are a quick and easy starting point that you can build on if your validation constraints become more complex.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found the solution by using a custom callback as mentioned by @Frasci. Will post code below.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code block for advised solution as custom callback validation.

I had to add another function in my upload entity which looks like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
/**
 * Function holds custom validation for fields in import/upload form
 * @Assert\Callback
 * @param ExecutionContextInterface $context
 */
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    // check new project name
    $newProjectName = $this->getNewprojectname();
    if(!empty($newProjectName)) {

        // letters only
        $pattern = '/[a-zA-Z]/';
        if($this->isPatternWrong($newProjectName, $pattern)) {
            $context
                ->buildViolation('Please use letters only.')
                ->atPath('newprojectname')
                ->addViolation();
        }

        // text max. 7 digits
        $maxlength = 7;
        if($this->isStringTooLong($newProjectName, $maxlength)) {
            $context
                ->buildViolation('Max. length 7 digits.')
                ->atPath('newprojectname')
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}

private function isPatternWrong($string, $pattern)
{
    $result = preg_match($pattern, $string);
    if($result === 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private function isStringTooLong($string, $length)
{
    if(strlen($string) > $length) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```